# Rails simple_form Editor for text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I want to combine any editor(tinymce, ckeditor, etc)  to simple_form text. It just doesn't show any effect when I use tinymce. I've used it before with bootstrap_form text_area and not used with simple_form before. Thanks.

```
<%= f.input :content, as: :text, label: false, placeholder: "Add  description...", input_html: {class: " tinymce" } %>
```

Comment: I think you also need a bit of javascript to initialize tinymce. Have you read its readme?

Comment: Oh yes, I applied everything but didnot initialize tinymce on the form.html with <%= tinymce %>! Thanks anyway for pointing to relook if I missed out on something.